# Indented Block Quote HTML Inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to recreate what I have in this google doc in html.  Basically how do I do an indented block quote that is indented on both sides and italicized?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```css
.block-quote {
  font-style: italic; /* The italic text */
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
In 2016, the AOA spent $1.6 million on lobbying efforts and $1.4 million in campaign contributions. These lobbying and campaign dollars are supposed to be under a guise of subtlety, but sometimes politicians and lobbyists forsake these rules for a more direct "quid pro quo". This story that a recovering lobbyist told you is a good example. 
<div class='block-quote'>
  When I was representing the wine and spirits distributors, I had scheduled a meeting with a member of the Nevada delegation. I had two of my Nevada clients with me, and we sat waiting patiently in the member's reception area before I was summoned into his office.
</div>
I was asked to leave my clients in the lobby for the time being. When I entered his office, he stood up and shook my hand, and then asked me point blank: 'Jimmy, we've called your PAC fundraiser on numerous occasions, and she hasn't returned our calls. So why exactly are you here for a meeting?.
<br>
<br>
He held in front of me a call sheet with the times and dates both he and his fundraiser had called us for donations. They were highlighted in yellow And my only response was "I don't know, Congressman, but take care of it." He told me he hoped so and then said I could bring my clients into his office. They walked in, we sat down as if nothing had happened, he said he supported every one of our pertinent legislative issues, and then we all shook hands and walked out. Now this guy is no longer a member of Congress, but he supported my clients' interest — and the legislation my clients wanted eventually passed the House and Senate and was signed into law.
```

Just add a div with the class `block-quote` and put your text inside that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [blockquote](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp) tag which indents it automatically, you can also use CSS to style it using text-align and font-style, or you could add padding to it.

HTML:

```
<blockquote cite="#" id="quote"> A famous quote </blockquote>
```

CSS:

```
#quote {
font-style: italic;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you could put the blockquote stuff in a new div and add some padding-left and padding.